# Scala.js demos do not display on iOS both under Safari and Chrome

Tags: scala.js

I've tried both the scala-js-fiddle demo & roll on iPad & iPhone. It displays a blank screen each time.
Has anybody been able to make it work?

**UPDATE**

For instance, when I start scala-js-fiddle.com under Safari, I get 47 errors in the console. The first one is:

```
[Log] TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'd.parseFromString(b,"text/html").documentElement') (client-opt.js, line 514)
[Error] TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'd.parseFromString(b,"text/html").documentElement')
    jk (client-opt.js, line 513)
    Qb (client-opt.js, line 14)
    Kg (client-opt.js, line 513)
    ei (client-opt.js, line 386)
    ei (client-opt.js, line 482)
    zs (client-opt.js, line 482)
    Nj (client-opt.js, line 481)
    q (client-opt.js, line 464)
    (fonction anonyme) (client-opt.js, line 468)
    wb (client-opt.js, line 465)
    jt (client-opt.js, line 333)
    Go (client-opt.js, line 468)
    (fonction anonyme) (client-opt.js, line 35)
    q (client-opt.js, line 466)
    dl (client-opt.js, line 262)
    qk (client-opt.js, line 306)
    Np (client-opt.js, line 262)
    (fonction anonyme) (client-opt.js, line 455)
    q (client-opt.js, line 466)
    z (client-opt.js, line 526)
    Ne (client-opt.js, line 455)
    Ge (client-opt.js, line 35)
    (fonction anonyme) (client-opt.js, line 34)
    q (client-opt.js, line 466)
    dl (client-opt.js, line 262)
    qk (client-opt.js, line 306)
    Np (client-opt.js, line 262)
    (fonction anonyme) (client-opt.js, line 455)
    q (client-opt.js, line 466)
    z (client-opt.js, line 526)
    Ne (client-opt.js, line 455)
    Ge (client-opt.js, line 35)
    Ce (client-opt.js, line 454)
    ga (client-opt.js, line 50)
    ac (client-opt.js, line 51)
    q (client-opt.js, line 51)
    dl (client-opt.js, line 262)
    qk (client-opt.js, line 306)
    Np (client-opt.js, line 262)
    (fonction anonyme) (client-opt.js, line 455)
    q (client-opt.js, line 466)
    z (client-opt.js, line 526)
    Ne (client-opt.js, line 455)
    Ge (client-opt.js, line 35)
    ga (client-opt.js, line 61)
    ga (client-opt.js, line 61)
    ga (client-opt.js, line 60)
    ga (client-opt.js, line 60)
    ga (client-opt.js, line 60)
    ga (client-opt.js, line 59)
    ac (client-opt.js, line 61)
    q (client-opt.js, line 62)
    dl (client-opt.js, line 262)
    qk (client-opt.js, line 306)
    Np (client-opt.js, line 262)
    (fonction anonyme) (client-opt.js, line 455)
    q (client-opt.js, line 466)
    z (client-opt.js, line 526)
    Ne (client-opt.js, line 455)
    Ge (client-opt.js, line 35)
    Ce (client-opt.js, line 454)
    (fonction anonyme) (client-opt.js, line 136)
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't put in any time trying to get them to work on iPad or iPhone; mainly because I don't own either device =P I can tell you it does work on my android phone just fine, although the pointer event handling doesn't work properly.

I don't think there's any insurmountable problem, it's likely I'm just calling one or two APIs that are blowing up on those devices, and causing everything else not to render. If you could provide stack traces to see why it's blowing up I would probably be able to find the problem code.

Source: I wrote them

Comment: Thanks. I posted details in an answer as copying the stack in a comment proved difficult.

Comment: @LiHaoyi the user seems new to StackOverflow, he posted his answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I am a scala.js newbie playing around the roll project. I am not sure if someone is still interested in this, but the game displays OK in safari after hacking the [following line](https://github.com/lihaoyi/roll/blob/master/src/main/scala/roll/Xml.scala#L100) with

```
    Group(el.childNodes.filter(node=>node.nodeType!=3 ).flatMap(node=>parse(node.asInstanceOf[Element])), misc) :: Nil.
```

Not sure why the "children" method of dom.Element is not functioning for me in safari.